# ng lint --fix=true doesn't fix linting errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lint

After creating a new project with "ng new" and after modifying tslint.json to use tabs instead of spaces, running "ng lint --fix=true" doesn't have any effect on .ts files:

[image]

```
ng lint --fix=true
```

only lists errors, but doesn't fix them. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/lint), it should though.

[image]

```
ERROR: 4:1   indent  tab indentation expected
ERROR: 5:1   indent  tab indentation expected
ERROR: 6:1   indent  tab indentation expected
ERROR: 9:1   indent  tab indentation expected
```

Env: Angular CLI: 10.1.7

Is the command wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the command `ng lint --fix` is correct and should fix the indentation.
I played around with tslint in a new Angular project, and while it did fix e.g. quotemarks, it does not fix the indentation for some reason (even though it should have a [fixer](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/)).

Maybe it would be an alternative to use [prettier](https://prettier.io/) for code formatting? It's a very reliable formatting tool, while tslint is deprecated and more of a linter than a formatter.

Comment: I had to add tab size, too, for auto-fix to work. But yeah, I guess prettier is the way to go.

Comment: from the linked [rule description](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/): 

"NOTE: auto-fixing will only convert invalid indent whitespace to the desired type, it will not fix invalid whitespace sizes."

that sucks and is an extra reason to stop using tslint.

Answer (score 0):

ng lint --fix using this command we can fix ->
**ERROR: 22:27  quotemark   " should be '**
this type of issues at one time running this command on your CMD.